# Implementing java interface with 3 methods with args in rhino javascript

Tags: javascript, java, interface, rhino

I need help with implementing java interface with 3 methods
in js. In java its seems like that:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xPath.setNamespaceContext(NamespaceContext() {
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            if (prefix.equals("media")) {
                return "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
            } else return null;
        }

        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }

        public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

but when I try to implement it in rhino using mozilla and oracle documentation it's doesn't work

```js
    var xPath = javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    var r = new javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext() {
    getNamespaceURI: function (prefix) { if(prefix === 'media') {return 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/';}
    else {return null;}
    },
    getPrefix: function (namespaceURI) { return null; },
    getPrefixes: function (namespaceURI) { return null; }
    };
    xPath.setNamespaceContext(r);
```

Is anybody know how to implement java interface multiple methods **with args** on rhino engine?

Comment: A block statement cant follow a constructor call. Use `Object.assign` or a set each property directly, e.g. `r.getNamespaceURI = function(){};`

Comment: What versions of Java are you using? Since Java 8 Rhino was switched with Nashorn.

Comment: Yes, I'am using Java 8, but I want to know, how to use method's args in javascript code. I read Nashorn documentation, but I didn't saw any examples with Interfaces which methods has any arguments

Comment: The fact the the methods have arguments shouldn't really matter though...